# I am receiving wrong calculation in SQL VIEW for Discount per ITEM

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am stuck,
I have 2 tables : `Sales` And `SalesDetails`

`Sales`: InvNum, Total, Discount, Nettotal etc...

`SalesDetails`: InvNum, ItemCode, Amount, etc..

The question is. I want to calculate the discount given per Item.
I did it in a view using the code.

```
SELECT dbo.Sales.InvNum, 
       dbo.SalesDetails.Amount
           /dbo.Sales.Total*dbo.Sales.Discount AS DiscountPerItem 
FROM dbo.Sales 
   INNER JOIN dbo.SalesDetails ON dbo.Sales.InvNum = dbo.SalesDetails.InvNum
```

It is working correctly but the problem is that it is not giving accurate result.
Example :

```
Sales.Total = 33,355,7.7500
Sales.Discount = 2,948.7500

SalesDetails.ItemCode = 1
SalesDetails.DiscountPerItem = 1.4744 (wrong result by SQL)
```

Etc (item2, 3, 4, .....)
That is the DiscountPerItem has to be **(198 / 33,355,7.7500 *  2,948.7500)** =  1.75 not = 1.4744
WHAT IS THE MISTAKE IN THIS CODE.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to multiply first to decrease rounding error

```
SELECT dbo.Sales.InvNum, 
       (dbo.SalesDetails.Amount*dbo.Sales.Discount)/dbo.Sales.Total 
           AS DiscountPerItem 
FROM dbo.Sales 
   INNER JOIN dbo.SalesDetails ON dbo.Sales.InvNum = dbo.SalesDetails.InvNum
```

Comment: I found the the Problem, Decimal calculation:   ROUND(CAST(dbo.SalesDetails.Total AS decimal(32 , 4)) / CAST(NULLIF (dbo.Sales.Total, 0) AS decimal(32 , 4)) * CAST(dbo.Sales.Discountmoney AS decimal(32 , 4)), 2)